# Uncaught Error: Class 'MongoClient' not found

Tags: php, mongodb

Trying to create a new Mongo connection using the following:
`$client = new Mongo();`

Sadly, this results in the following error: "Uncaught Error: Class 'Mongo' not found in". I've also tried MongoClient, just in case this is the issue.

To make things more confusing, running phpinfo() in the same file results in the following.
[image]

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out that this is an issue in the official driver documentation.

You need to use `new MongoDB\Client` and use the PHP library as well, rather than `new MongoDB\Driver\Client` as suggested.

Answer (score 2):

There are two PHP MongoDB packages, [the Mongo extension](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mongo.php) and the newer [MongoDB driver](http://php.net/manual/en/set.mongodb.php). You have the newer one, but you're writing code for the older one.

Comment: Thanks! Can you tell me what I should be writing instead to create the client?

Comment: @OliverDunk The docs there suggest using http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-php-library/ to use the driver. Lots of examples there.

Comment: Now getting this error: `Uncaught Error: Class 'MongoDB\Driver\Client' not found`